# Convert None to Null in pyodbc while parsing TVP

Tags: python, sql-server

I have 2 SQL Server procedures. Each procedure sitting in different server.

1. GetData - Procedure from source server, which gets the data
2. SetData - Procedure from target server. which takes TVP as param and inserts data into tables of target server's database.

The result from GetData is as follows.

```
[[1, 'Sea', 'Rmm, T', 31, True, None], [2, 'Sea', 'Fmm, T', 22, False, None]]
```

When I send these values as is to SetData TVP, I get the following error.

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)')

The sixth column is a `TINYINT` column.

The Python code working fine when I replace None with ''. But it is expected to insert NULL into SQL Server table. But it is getting inserted as 0 as it is a `TINYINT` column.

When I try to type cast (replace) "None" to "Null", I am getting the following error:

> pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Null' to data type tinyint. (245) (SQLParamData); [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The data for the table-valued parameter 1 doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is: 245, state: 1 (8062); [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I know nothing about it, but the error suggests you are passing the string null rather than the value null. My guess is you have to set the null value specifically.

Comment: I agree with you @DaleK. But how can I set the null value specifically?

Comment: Thats where I can't help you as I don't know the technology... surely google can answer?

Comment: Oh! okay. I've also googled for it, mostly the answers are like converting list to string and then replacing None with Null. This does not work in my case.

Comment: After some more research I found that, it works fine if the first row of the TVP does not contain Nulls. But it is not always guaranteed that first row can not contain nulls.

Comment: Are you using a recent version of pyodbc? This sounds similar to [Type mismatch for None/NULL value in a cell in a table-valued parameter. #596](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/596).

Comment: I have had a look at #596. But it seems it is still unresolved:(